# golang ORM name of table

Tags: postgresql, go, orm

I have some code to create the table in Postgres DB

```
import (
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
type Table struct {
    Id   int    `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name string `gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
    Addr string `gorm:"type:varchar(100)"`
}
func main() {
    db, _ := gorm.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=poilo777 dbname=mydb sslmode=disable")
    defer db.Close()
    db.CreateTable(&Table{}) 
    user := &Table{Name: "ololo", Addr: "pololo"}
```

there are 2 problems, i faced:
1) in database created a table "tables" instead of "Table"
2) how can I insert data in existing another tables? (for example "users")

Answer (score 6):

1) You can set Table's table name to be `table`

```
func (Table) TableName() string {
    return "table"
}
```

Another way is to set singularTable true, then `Table`'s default table name will be `table` instead of `tables`. But it will affect all tables the same.

```
set db.SingularTable(true)
```

2) In ORM you should define your table object. Here is a struct called `Table`. Gorm will create a new table called `tables` in database unless you want to overwrite table's name you can follow step 1.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the golang Postgres Client will **implicitly** use the pluralized version of *your* `struct` name[1]. For example

```golang
type Student struct {
   FirstName string
   LastName string
}
// will create a table name `students`
```

You can override it like the following, depending on what you are using

### GORM

```golang
// Set User's table name to be `profiles`
func (Student) TableName() string {
  return "college_students"
}
```

### GO-PQ

```golang
type Student struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"college_students,alias:g"``
}
```

https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#Pluralized-Table-Name

Answer (score -2):

My solving of this problem:

```
    db.Table("my_table").CreateTable(&Table{})

    user := &Table{Name: "ololo", Addr: "pololo"}
    db.Table("my_table").Create(user)
```

This code creates table `my_table` as I wanted